# Как обработать двойной клик по toolstripmenuitem?

Tags: c#, winforms

Добавил на форму `notifyicon` к нему привязал `contextmenustrip`, к элементу применил `toolstripmenuitem.doubleclick = true;` и привязал к нему событие `doubleclick` которое выводит `MessageBox.Show("что-нибудь");` Но по `toolstripmenuitem` не получается кликнуть 2 раза, после первого клика оно пропадает как бы быстро я не кликал. В чём проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данная опция (`toolStripMenuItem1.DoubleClickEnabled = true;`) нужна когда есть выпадающее меню, например

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тогда двойной клик уместен и сработает.  (кроме того `toolstripmenuitem.doubleclick` это событие, свойство было указано выше).
Если же выпадающего меню нет, то нужда в двойном клике отпадает.